# Sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier F-Score Different Results with Each run

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to train a decision tree classifier using Python. I'm using `MinMaxScaler()` to scale the data, and `f1_score` for my evaluation metric. The strange thing is that I'm noticing my model giving me different results in a pattern at each run.

`data` in my code is a `(2000, 7)` `pandas.DataFrame`, with 6 feature columns and the last column being the target value. Columns 1, 3, and 5 are categorical data.

The following code is what I did to preprocess and format my data:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score


# Data Preprocessing Step
# =============================================================================
data = pd.read_csv("./data/train.csv")

X = data.iloc[:, :-1]
y = data.iloc[:, 6]

# Choose which columns are categorical data, and convert them to numeric data.
labelenc = LabelEncoder()
categorical_data = list(data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns)

for i in range(len(categorical_data)):
    X[categorical_data[i]] = labelenc.fit_transform(X[categorical_data[i]])


# Convert categorical numeric data to one-of-K data, and change y from Series to ndarray.
onehotenc = OneHotEncoder()
X = onehotenc.fit_transform(X).toarray()
y = y.values

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_val)
```

The next code is for the actual decision tree model training:

```python
dectree = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced')
dectree = dectree.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
predictions = dectree.predict(X_val_scaled)
score = f1_score(y_val, predictions, average='macro')

print("Score is = {}".format(score))
```

The output that I get (i.e. the score) varies, but in a pattern. For example, it would circulate among data within the range of `0.39` and `0.42`.

On some iterations, I even get the `UndefinedMetricWarning`, that claims "F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples."

I'm familiar with what the `UndefinedMetricWarning` means, after doing some searching on this community and Google. I guess the two questions I have may be organized to:

1. Why does my output vary for each iteration? Is there something in the preprocessing stage that happens which I'm not aware of?
2. I've also tried to use the F-score with other data splits, but I always get the warning. Is this unpreventable?

Thank you.

Comment: try with `dectree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the comment. I've tried with that and noticed that I no longer get the warning message and also get a consistent value. May I ask why 42 though? Also, I've noticed that some values for `random_state` produce the warning message but others don't... would you happen to know why?

Comment: Use `random_state` everywhere where it is applicable. In your case, its `train_test_split()` and `DecisionTreeClassifier()`. Also, use `stratify` option in `train_test_split()` to get a balanced split (classes) between train and test data (which may help in avoiding the `UndefinedMetric` warning).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @VivekKumar. I didn't know about these methods. I'll make sure to keep them in mind next time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting the dataset into train and test which randomly divides sets for both train and test. Due to this, when you train your model with different training data everytime, and testing it with different test data, you will get a range of F score depending on how well the model is trained.

In order to replicate the result each time you run, use `random_state` parameter. It will maintain a random number state which will give you the same random number each time you run. This shows that the random numbers are generated in the same order. This can be any number.

```
#train test split
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)

#Decision tree model
dectree = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced', random_state=2018)
```